# Android Biometric : IllegalStateException. At least one biometric must be enrolled to create keys that require user authentication

Tags: android, androidx, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am using the android Biometricx library for face and fingerprint authentication. When only FaceID is registered and I try to create secret key I am getting "***IllegalStatException: At least one biometric must be enrolled to create keys that require user authentication***"

I am trying to create **secretKey** like this

```
            try {
                
                mKeyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                        // of the key
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .build());
                secretKey = mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                    | CertificateException | IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Create Key "+ e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

The code works fine when fingerprint is registered. This happens only when FaceId is registered. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just because a device supports face recognition doesn't automatically mean that it can be used to allow access to keystore keys to third-party applications. For that to be supported, certain requirements have to be met, as specified in [the Android CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd). Note that this is beyond your control as an app developer, at least until Android R, which allows you to trust _Weak_ biometrics if you should choose to do so.

Comment: @Michael I understand. The error thrown should be wrong because it says at least one biometric must be enrolled (I have already registered Face ID).

Comment: How does the same piece of code work when both Fingerprint and FaceId are registered in the same device?

Comment: Well, if the face detection on the device you're testing on is considered _Weak_ (which may be the case for pretty much every Android device right now except the Pixel 4), then from the point of the Biometric API you don't have any usable biometrics enrolled.

Comment: If there are multiple types of biometrics that could be used, then it's my understanding that the user will be able to select their preferred biometric somehow (e.g. in the Settings app). Your app doesn't really have any control over what is used (except for the _Strong_ vs _Weak_ distinction on Android R).

Comment: @Michael Is there a way to check if an enrolled biometric is Weak? or we just need to go with the Exception

Comment: There is a catch here. If the user has enrolled both, he gets a prompt to select any one for authentication. Users can choose FaceId and authenticate, even though it was considered Weak.

Comment: That's sounds like a bug in the implementation of the BiometricPrompt (or perhaps in an OEM customization). You may want to file a bug report with the responsible company.

Comment: Got the reason for the bug here, it was due to not passing the crypto object while authenticating with biometric prompt. If passed, the biometric API will not use unsecured biometrics, if the crypto object is not passed, it will show all available biometrics.

Comment: I appreciate this an old post but @Michael, I was wondering if you had a source that explains you can't use weak biometrics in conjunction with the keystore.  You mention the Android CDD and also Android R but I can't find information specifically relating to this.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm guessing that I was referring to this part of the Android 10 CDD: "To allow access to keystore keys to third-party applications, device implementations:

* [C-0-2] MUST meet the requirements for **Strong** as defined in this document."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the issue here. Its all got to do with the setting of `.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)`

If this key is set to `true` while generating a key, that means at least one secure biometric/unlock pin/pattern must be enrolled. Since the key was set to `true` and only unsecured authentication methods were present, the error `At least one biometric must be enrolled to create keys that require user authentication` was thrown

**Note:** Face ID in Samsung is considered unsecured as of now. That was the reason for the above issue